# Does android notify an application/activity when a savedInstanceState is never going to be restored again?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I use xamarin and i have a question about screen rotation and savedInstanceState.

I use ViewModels that are shared between iOS and Android. Each Fragment/Activity has a ViewModel property. This property is lost when the screen rotated and the activity gets rebuild.

I know that I can use "ConfigurationChanges" or other solutions where I for example lock a specific orientation?

But I was thinking about using a ViewModel registry where each view model stored with an identifier. This identifier would then be stored inside de savedInstanceState, when an activity runs onCreate and there is a viewmodel identifier in the savedInstanceState then it can restore the viewmodel from the registry.

The problem is that I now; after a while; have a registry with a lot of viewmodels that will never be restored again because the user has navigated away a couple of times.

Has android a way to tell if a savedInstanceState will berestored in the future? Or does android have a callback (maybe in application) where I can get notified about about-to-be-thrown-away-savedInstanceState's? Then I can cleanup the registery.

Other options beside a registery are also appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For the Android app, do your ViewModels extend the android ViewModel class?

Comment: If not, you could use a ViewModel class (from architecture components) to store your more general ViewModel in and tie it to the Activity/Fragment. That way, the general ViewModel would survive a config change.

Comment: Hi @kazume, That looks like a viable solution. Its sad that Xamarin has not released stable bindings for the lifecycle libraries yet.

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not very familiar with Xamarin. Hope it works nevertheless!

Comment: I tried. But it requires me to update a lot of libraries to prerelease and alpha version. It's really annoying that they are active on such a library for 3 months and then they leave is in some kind of unfinished prerelease state for half a year or more.

Comment: The Android ViewModel is exactly what I need though. Kind of frustrating that I cannot use it at the moment.

Comment: I hear you! I've been particularly happy with the introduction of arch components myself.

Comment: @kazume Xamarin literally released a release version of their bindings last Tuesday, a couple of hours after I asked this question.  (Maybe they are watching :p) I'll Try again with their new release versions

Comment: Nice, good to hear! Enjoy the magic :)